# Given LSD's and values - output significance letters

Tags: r

I've been looking for library functions to do this, but I'm surprised that I cannot find one.

There are quite a few stats functions in R that do the statistical test then output 
a table that includes letters denoting significance groups, for example LSD.test.[An example of how LSD's might be calculated and used to make multicomparison letters, used in a graph](https://rdrr.io/cran/agricolae/man/LSD.test.html)

There are others.  All of the examples I could find tend to work from a model object, and then do their job. However, I already have the LSD values and the means -- and want to work directly with them. I've been looking for a common function that all of these multicomparison methods use to do this final step, but can't find one.

So, this is what I want to do...given the least significant difference between values (LSD) and the mean values them selves:

```
lsd <- 1.0
vals <- c(2,3,3.5,4,4.2,6.0)
```

I want to I want to produce output something like:

```
2 a
3 b
3.5 bc
4 c
4.2 c
6.0 d
```

,where values followed by the same letter are not significantly different, based on the least significant difference value.

Ideally, it would be best if it could handle the list of values un-ordered...

```
vals <- c(6.0, 2, 3.5, 4.0, 4.2, 3)
```

producing the output:

```
6.0 d
 2  a
3.5 bc
4.0 b
4.2 c
3 c
```

I've been thinking that most of these LSD.test and multicompare functions 
are probably using a base function to put together the letter list -- but I have not been able to find it.

Working through the problem, I think this does the trick, but it's pretty ugly...

```
 lsd.letters <- function(vals, lsd) {
  #find their order
  #record their order
  indx <- order(vals)
  #sort their order
  srt <- vals[indx]
  #assign a variable of letters
  lts <- letters
  #create a character vector
  siglets <- rep("", length(vals))#c("a",rep("", length(vals)-1))
  #use a single pass through the list of means
  #use the first letter a for the lowest value
  itlet <- 1
  for (i in c(1:(length(vals)))){
    crnt <- srt[i]
    clet <- lts[itlet]

    #is this value within the LSD of any other value in the remaining list 

    ix <- which(srt[i:length(srt)] < (crnt+lsd))+i-1


    for (ix2 in ix){
        newletter <- 0
        if (length(intersect( unlist(strsplit(siglets[i], "")), unlist(strsplit(siglets[ix2], "")))) == 0){
          #If the  string for this mean does not already contain a letter in common for the current step mean... assign the letter
          #siglets[ix2] <- paste0(siglets[ix2],clet)
          newletter <- 1
        }
    }

    if (newletter == 1){
      siglets[ix] <- paste0(siglets[ix],clet)
      itlet <-  itlet + 1  
        }


  }
  siglets
}
```

It's ugly, and I am not yet sorting the output (sorting it is easy).

Is there a library function to do this?  Or has anyone written a better approach to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is unclear. Where do the letter come from in your output? Are you trying to develop a `format` method or `print` method? Can you make your question more pointed and define the input you have and the output you want.

Comment: Sorry, trosendal -- I've added some more explanation.  The question is about using a least significant difference value to assign multicomparison letters to the values. Usually in publications you will have a list of values followed by letters and a statment "values followed by the same letter are not significantly different at the P < 0.05 level".